# Getting all records before a particular month and year

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with separate Month and Year fields - I need to query this table to only pick up the records before a certain month and year in the past, which will change on a regular basis. (For the sake of clarity I have hard-coded the date to be November 2016)

```
DECLARE @Month INT
DECLARE @Year INT

SET @Month = 11
SET @Year = 2016

SELECT * FROM Items 
WHERE [Month] <= @Month AND [Year] <= @Year
```

This doesn't get the results I want, because pre-2016 December items would never be picked up due to the Month criteria.

I tried to work around this by concatenating the Month & Year fields:

```
SET @YearMonth = 201611

SELECT * FROM Items 
WHERE cast([Year] as nvarchar(4)) + cast([Month] as nvarchar(2)) <= @YearMonth
```

But this returns items in 2017. (Not sure why?)

Can the above query be fixed, or is there a better way of getting the desired results?

Comment: How about (year * 100 + month) < yyyymm? As number they will work a lot better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Items 
WHERE [Year] < @Year
OR ([Year] = @Year AND [Month] <= @Month)`

Translation:

1. Get *all* records from *before* my selected year
2. Get those from the selected year itself only from  the selected month or before.

Answer (score 2):

In your last query, you are getting 2017 records because `20171` <= `201711`. So to fix your query you'd have to do something like

```
cast([Year] as nvarchar(4)) + right('00' + [Month], 2) <= @YearMonth
```

It would be better to store dates as `date(time)`, rather than year, month and day in separate attributes.

Comment: I agree with your last statement, they should use the `date` data type.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it's data I have inherited, and the table doesn't contain any day data.

Comment: @finjo - I would add a new calculated field to the table, which creates a date from the month and year. Just set the day to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
select  * from Items 
where convert(date,concat([Year],'-',[Month],'-','01')) > 
convert(date,concat(@Year,'-',@Month,'-','01'))
```